# Replace part of string globally in dataframe

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have following dataframe:

```
id   feature
1    p.Asp25Asn
2    p.Gly25Asn
3    p.Ile20Tyr
```

I would like to replace a part of column 'feature'.

For example: Asp when matched should be replaed by 'D'. Asn when matched should be replace by 'N' and so on for other column values like Gly --> G, Ile -->I, Tyr -->Y

The expected output is:

```
id   feature
1    p.D25N
2    p.G25N
3    p.I20Y
```

I am writing a function which matches a condition and perform such replacement globally. If there are better solution available, please suggest.

Thanks

Comment: Can you explain what is the replacement function? Should the last one be p.I20R?

Comment: @ItamarMushkin No thats not true. I have edited my question for more clarity

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use[pandas.DataFrame.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) using a dictionary.

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'id':[1,2,3],'feature':['p.Asp25Asn','p.Gly25Asn','p.Ile20Tyr']})
>>>df
   id     feature
0   1  p.Asp25Asn
1   2  p.Gly25Asn
2   3  p.Ile20Tyr

mydict={'Asp':'D','Asn':'N','Gly':'G','Ile':'I','Tyr':'Y'}
df = df.replace({"feature": mydict},regex=True)
>>>df
   id   feature
0   1    p.D25N
1   2    p.G25N
2   3    p.I20Y
```